# Is it possible to create an ongoing vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vacuum, flow

This is a crazy thought but here goes. We all know about creating a vacuum in a jar but it is feasible to create a continuous vacuum or low pressure to reduce drag by dispelling or otherwise creating a vacuuming between say a basketball and the air around it when thrown?

Comment: It's possible to put dimples on the ball to cause turbulent air to close more closely around the ball, thereby decreasing drag.

Comment: Sure.  Just pump all the air out of the gymnasium.  But I don't think the basketball players will like that.